# NUnit Unit Testing which involves dbcontext

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the code below, which is now testable. The problem is when it reaches the Entity Framework (EF) related code, it kinda hangs there (infinite loop). I think my interim solution is to comment out my EF related code.

I understand that to test EF, I might need thing like MOQ or integration testing which I plan to come out with later on. Meanwhile, how do I 'split' out all this EF code, so that I can perform NUnit testing for other testable code? Here is one of the methods I have:

```
public void PlaceDeposit(BankAccount account, decimal _transaction_amt)
{   

    if (_transaction_amt <= 0)               
        _msgPrinter.PrintMessage("Amount needs to be more than zero. Try again.", false);
    else if (_transaction_amt % 10 != 0)
        _msgPrinter.PrintMessage($"Key in the deposit amount only with multiply of 10. Try again.", false);
    else if (!PreviewBankNotesCount(_transaction_amt))
        _msgPrinter.PrintMessage($"You have cancelled your action.", false);
    else
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction()
        {
            AccountID = account.Id,
            BankAccountNoTo = account.AccountNumber,
            TransactionType = TransactionType.Deposit,
            TransactionAmount = _transaction_amt,
            TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        repoTransaction.InsertTransaction(transaction);
        // Add transaction record - End

        account.Balance = account.Balance + _transaction_amt;

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        _msgPrinter.PrintMessage($"You have successfully deposited {Utility.FormatAmount(_transaction_amt)}", true);
    }
}
```

I have this test method in NUnit, which works fine:

```
[TestCase("Amount needs to be more than zero. Try again.",0)]
[TestCase("Amount needs to be more than zero. Try again.",-1)]
[TestCase("Key in the deposit amount only with multiply of 10. Try again.", 1)]
[TestCase("Key in the deposit amount only with multiply of 10. Try again.", 5)]
public void ShowErrorMessage_OnPlaceDeposit(string expectedMessage, decimal transactionAmount)
{
    // Arrange - Start
    var mock = new MockMessagePrinter();

    MeybankATM atmCustomer = new MeybankATM(new RepoBankAccount(), new RepoTransaction(), mock);

    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount()
    {
        FullName = "John",
        AccountNumber = 333111,
        CardNumber = 123,
        PinCode = 111111,
        Balance = 2000.00m,
        isLocked = false
    };
    // Arrange - End

    // Act
    atmCustomer.PlaceDeposit(bankAccount, transactionAmount);

    // Assert                       
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, mock.Message);
}
```

Now, all I have I left is to test the balance update part:

```
account.Balance = account.Balance + _transaction_amt;
```

Comment: Off-topic: I would change all of your `else if` statements to just `if` statements with `return`s in them and get rid of the `else` statement.

Comment: As for testing EF, take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking) from Microsoft. You will indeed need to Mock EF